# How to autoupdate the excel dates using java

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I'm automating a scenario in which I need excel file to be updated with current date on daily basis( using java or any macro).For this to update on daily basis,I need to open and close the file so that it can save the current date.I'm using a continuous integration system where in, automation gets triggered at 5am.Before it triggers,I need to open the file and close.
I tried open and close using JXL.But, i'm not sure of reference issues which might get disturbed.
Can this be somehow automated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a java function that returns the current date and write it to the excel file using jxl.
To make it automated visit this http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html. Set this to auto start service. I guess that will solve your problem.